# Is it possible to create a dynamic union statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Let's say I have a table like this. We can call it sales:

```
id  | purchaserID | item |      date   |
1   |      1      |  A1  |  2014-10-31 |
2   |      1      |  A2  |  2014-10-30 |
3   |      1      |  A3  |  2014-10-19 |
4   |      1      |  A2  |  2014-10-26 |
5   |      2      |  B1  |  2014-10-31 |
6   |      2      |  B2  |  2014-10-28 |
7   |      2      |  B3  |  2014-10-30 | 
8   |      1      |  C1  |  2014-10-27 |
9   |      2      |  B4  |  2014-10-01 |
```

What I want to do is get the latest N (we'll make it 3 in the case) dates of purchase for each purchaserID. I know this is possible, courtesy of other questions on Stack. I know that one way (even if it's not the best way) is to select the latest 3 dates for each purchaser and union them together:

```
(SELECT * FROM sales WHERE purchaserID = 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM sales WHERE purchaserID = 2 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3)
```

What I want to know - is there a way to make this dynamically union all purchaserIDs? What if ID 3 makes a purchase, now I have to recreate my query to get the latest 3 dates for each purchaser.

I've already built an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13071d/2) for you to play with.

Comment: No. But there are other ways to solve this. See my answer at the other thread. A faster solution than mine would use variables.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks. This is not a duplicate question at all in my opinion. My question is about the union, not about how to get top n rows.

Comment: FYI, I didn't mark it so.

Comment: @Strawberry didn't mean to point a finger, but I guess I'm curious on your take? Are users allowed to vote to undo that sort of thing?

Comment: Yes. They can, and they have.

Comment: The duplicate has the answer.  You don't need a UNION, just GROUP BY each purchaser and select the top N results.

Comment: @JasonMArcher that wasn't the question. Thanks to strawberry I've realized that what I want is simply just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you are looking for without having to union:

```
CREATE TABLE #Purchases (
id  int, 
purchaserID int, 
item varchar(2),      
date datetime,
)
INSERT INTO #Purchases VALUES
(1   ,      1      ,  'A1'  ,  '2014-10-31') ,
(2   ,      1      ,  'A2'  ,  '2014-10-30') ,
(3   ,      1      ,  'A3'  ,  '2014-10-19') ,
(4   ,      1      ,  'A2'  ,  '2014-10-26') ,
(5   ,      2      ,  'B1'  ,  '2014-10-31') ,
(6   ,      2      ,  'B2'  ,  '2014-10-28') ,
(7   ,      2      ,  'B3'  ,  '2014-10-30'), 
(8   ,      1      ,  'C1'  ,  '2014-10-27') ,
(9   ,      2      ,  'B4'  ,  '2014-10-01') 

SELECT *
FROM #purchases a
WHERE ((
  SELECT count(*) FROM #Purchases as b WHERE 
    b.date > a.date AND
    b.purchaserID = a.purchaserID
) + 1) <= 3
order by purchaserId, date desc

DROP TABLE #Purchases
```

Returns:

```
id  purchaserID item    date
1   1   A1  2014-10-31 00:00:00.000
2   1   A2  2014-10-30 00:00:00.000
8   1   C1  2014-10-27 00:00:00.000
5   2   B1  2014-10-31 00:00:00.000
7   2   B3  2014-10-30 00:00:00.000
6   2   B2  2014-10-28 00:00:00.000
```

This statement is O(n^2) though. Hope this dataset isn't extraordinarily large.

Comment: So this can't be done with a union? At least, not dynamically.